# MicrosoftCharts - Chart.SaveImage() to MemoryStream sometimes throws OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, winforms

I capture chart image as png with such an extension method:

```
    public static Stream GetChartImageStream(this Chart chart, int imgWidth, double imgFactor)
    {
        var imgStream = new MemoryStream();

        var previousSize = chart.Size;
        chart.Size = new Size(new Point(imgWidth, Convert.ToInt32(imgWidth / imgFactor)));

        chart.SaveImage(imgStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        // set the old size back
        chart.Size = previousSize;

        return imgStream;
    }
```

An how it gets called:

```
Chart chart;
var chartStream = chart.GetChartImageStream(1010, 1.50d);
chartStream.Dispose();
```

The problem is that it sometimes throws an `OutOfMemoryException` in line

```
chart.SaveImage(imgStream, ChartImageFormat.Png)
```

and yes, I have a lot of free memory at that time;

I cannot see anything that I could be doing wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure at all, but resizing a complex chart does take some time; maybe adding a safety delay could help..?

Comment: Yea, maybe you are right, I will try that